# Laravel, related model reuturened names

Tags: laravel, model, alias, relation

I have a model that has a related model

```
class A extends Model{

public function niceName()
    {
        return this->hasOne('App\NiceName2' ...);
    }
```

In the controller when I retrieve data with submodel the result is like

a[nice_name_2] (using the table name) and I would like it to be a[NiceName2].

Is there a way to have an alias for the returned result? In cakePHP i know there is propertyName to set this on relations. Laravel has a similar feature?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. If you get `A` like `$a = A::with(["niceName"])->first();`, then you should be accessing sub-model like `$niceName = $a->niceName;`. Include all code necessary to recreate.

Comment: i convert it toArray (not accessing it as objects) and then the array name is table_full_name instead of ModelName.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that in your question, but yes, as Devon has said, serializing (converting to array/json/etc) will convert to **snake_case**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel uses the convention of camelCase for method names and snake_case for attributes.  I'm not sure there's an easy way around this.

When Laravel serializes the data, it converts relationships to snake_case, by convention.  So `NiceName2` would become `nice_name2` when you execute `toArray()` or when the model is serialized (either in a JSON response or otherwise).

How this works is:

When you access `$model->nice_name2` it converts the property name back to `niceName2` to check for a relationship method with that name.  When serializing, it converts the relationship `niceName2` to the attribute name `nice_name2`.

Comment: now it's clear to me why this is happening. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully make it a bit more clear.